# Autolayout - Why does "Vertical Spacing" sometimes attach to the opposite side of a view?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

When I select "Vertical Spacing" in interface builder, I expect the *bottom* of the upper view and the *top* of the lower view to have a relationship.  However, frequently what seems to happen is that the bottom of the lower view gets linked to the bottom of the upper view.  Then at runtime the bottom view will have the wrong frame (after resizes, animations, etc.).  Is there a way I can ensure that views are consistently linked bottom to top?

[image: Toolbar gets too small]

[EDIT]

Here's another example. I set a height of 419px.  I select "Top space to top layout guide".  But instead it puts a constraint for how far the *bottom* of the imageview should be from the top of the superview.  Then I change the height from 419px to 374px, and the view has correct height, but a gap at the top.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean. Can you attach xib with example of the layout, or try to explain again in other words?

Comment: Sorry, Sergey, but the issue went away.  Wasn't the first time I've experienced this, but I don't know how to duplicate it. (And if I did, I would just stop doing that! ;-)

Comment: Ran into this again today and added another example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in the latest versions of Xcode.  You can now select which part of the constraint you want to attach to.  It may attach wrong initially, but the constraint editing controls are much better now.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this many times (usually when attaching the top of something to the topLayoutGuide), and I've put it down to a bug in Interface Builder. It *seems* like the issue has gone away in the betas of Xcode 5.1

The only workaround I've found is to initially move your view away from the view you're attaching it to, and *then* create the constraint. In this situation, Xcode will usually do the right thing. Then manually edit the constraint's constant back to 0 (or whatever you want it to be).

Comment: This seemed promising, but it resulted in the same "Vertical Space - (-355)" constraint.  Hopefully it gets fixed in the next version though!

Comment: Also, how are you creating your constraints? Ctrl + dragging?

Comment: Yes.  Usually I control drag from the view onto itself, but I also tried control dragging onto "Top Layout Guide" in the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding vertical spacing, try by adding "Top spacing to nearest neighbor" constraint.  Please refer attached image,

[image: Top spacing to nearest neighbor]

Hope this will help.